# Order Facebook highscores by country

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I'm working on a Facebook game where scores get saved using the Scores API, while this all works fine, our client wants to be able to filter the highscores by country, I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this.

When returning the scores, the user object only contains the ID and the name, it would be pretty stupid to get the country fo each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier way would be to get user country on application install time.
You can do this by adding user location permission to authentication dialog which appears first time
when the user visits your app.

See `user_hometown` and `user_location` here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Then you can easily look all the user countries from your database, and sort according to country.

Comment: Yes, so this means I have to add users to my database as well?
This was my idea at first, but I was hoping this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @woutr_be yes, that would have to be done, and should be done, mostly to cache user info like name,facebook id,birthday etc

Comment: It's a canvas game that doesn't really need any backend, it's just a simple game, so was hoping to avoid all this. But thanks, guess I'll have to do this anyway.